# How to extract the variance covariance matrix for particular values?

Tags: r

I would like to extract the variance covariance matrix for variables b and c and have some struggles to find the right command. My original data frame has more then 100 variables. therefore to know a command to exctract that would be great

Given data:

```
                a<-rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
                b<-rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
                c<-rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
                d<-rbinom(1000, size = 1, prob = .5)
                e<-rbinom(1000, size = 1, prob = .5)
                f<-rbinom(1000, size = 1, prob = .5)
                data<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e,f)

               test<-glm(a~b+c+d+e+f,data=data)

               pe.glmCube<-test$coefficients[2:3] # point estimates
```

I tried the same with the variance matrix. But it seems senseless to do it that way:

```
               vc.glmCube <- vcov(test[2:3]) # var-cov matrix
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
vcov(test)[c("b", "c"), c("b", "c")]
#              b             c
#b  1.083964e-03 -2.532682e-05
#c -2.532682e-05  9.779278e-04
```

Comment: that was quick. Thank you!!

Comment: You dont know what subscript out of bounds means in that context?

Comment: I do. All of this is just matrix subsetting. You can reproduce the error for your example with `vcov(test)[c("x", "z"), c("x", "z")]`. `x` and `z` are not part of the design matrix.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you for your time